# Determining when to use which Android components?

Tags: java, android, view, android-activity

Firstly, I'm new to Android (so I apologize if this question is ignorant) but have some experience in Java. I have been reading a book on Android and remain slightly confused about the basic components (activities, intent, content providers, and broadcast receivers).

I have a few java classes that I'm wanting to convert over to Android but I'm not sure what type of components they should be.

If a class does simple conversions, should that be an intent?
Or, if a class draws, should it be an activity?

I'm just looking for someone who can explain the components a bit better than the references at android and perhaps give some good examples of each component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confused about some of the terminology. An activity is what the user interacts with (displays the content, contains the listeners for buttons, etc.) So when you launch an app and see something on the screen, an Activity is what draws all the buttons/components on screen and contains the code for user interaction. An intent is kind of a way to tell activity to launch something else. For example, if you were on your main activity, and wanted to change the Activity when the user clicked something, you would create and start an intent specifying that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Read this basic tutorial. It should be somewhat clearer than the official docs. 
http://androiddevelopertips.com/activity/understanding-activities-in-android.html

Comment: after reading that, it slightly clears things up for me. So if I understand things correctly, I can leave my conversion class as is and call it when needed. And if I have a class that draws graphics, I would want it to extend an Activity?

Comment: Most likely yes. Think of activities as sort of a "page" you see on a website. It might be possible to have an extra class, but it just makes things more organized if you draw inside the Activity class. Otherwise you would have to pass contexts into the separate drawing class, which can get confusing/messy sometimes.

Comment: If the class draws a graph and is constantly manipulated would it be better to make it as a view or activity? Reason I ask is because I override `onDraw` in View